# Why there is a partition type in GUID Partition Table?

Tags: boot, partitioning, bootloader, gpt

Why there is a partition type in GUID Partition Table?

What are they using for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because partitions hold different types of data.  [Here's a list of some of them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)

Operating systems use the type code to decide whether a partition is one that it's interested in.  For example, Windows only creates drive letters for partitions with specific types that it's aware of; it'll ignore partitions belonging to other operating systems, since it doesn't expect to understand them.  And EFI firmware looks for a partition with a special "system" type code and uses it for booting.